# Core Service endpoint Address

Tags: core-service

```
<service
    behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.ContentManager.ServiceHost.IISHost.CoreServiceBehavior"
    name="Tridion.ContentManager.ServiceHost.IISHost.CoreService2013">
    <endpoint address="basicHttp"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="CoreService_basicHttpBinding"
        name="basicHttp"
        bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013"
        contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.ICoreService2013" />
    <endpoint address="wsHttp"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="CoreService_wsHttpBinding"
        name="wsHttp"
        bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013"
        contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.ISessionAwareCoreService2013">

    --- Other Bindings---
```

I don't see address key having any URL in endpoint. Is it right? Acutally I have use wsHttp Binding to work with impersonation and it's not working, don't know why, however basicHttpBinding is working fine.

for below client configuration I m gotting following error "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via"

```
<client>
    <endpoint
        address="https://dev_server_address/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/wsHttp"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="wsHttp"
        contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService"
        name="wsHttp" />
```

Comment: It's not clear what is not working. You wan't to connect to wsHttp endpoint and you can't? What's the error message? Show us your client code

Comment: @Andrey: Updated my question with error details and client  configuration

Answer (score 1):

You client config is missing the `security` node. Try to add `<security mode="Transport">`